# Show delete button on mouseover and after delete remove li or div

Tags: javascript, button, mouseover

In php code some english words are populating from database (postgres) and put into li.
What I need is each li should have delete button which is hidden during load. When mouse is hover that image should be visible.

After that, delete operation will be performed on database side using ajax and that li will be removed.(no problem with it as I already coded).

I gone though this [link](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/02/php-mysql-download-counter/), but instead of only button click event is fired for whole li block.I don't want this because in future I will add more button like edit,spam like that.

Same thing can be seen when you hover on comment you have made and delete icon will appear in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery will save your day.

```
<li>words <img src="delete.jpg" style="display:none;"/></li>

$('li').mouseover(function(event)
{
   $(this).find('img').show();
});

$('li').mouseout(function(event)
{
   $(this).find('img').hide();
});
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure jQuery doesn't cache selections by tag name, in which case, `$('li').mouseover(...).mouseout(...);` will be more performant.  Further, you should really use `$('li').hover(...)`.

Comment: I'm curious to know whats wrong with my answer that caused a downvote?

Comment: what about click event should I have to include img inside anchor tag like <a href='#' class='link1' id='link1'><img src="delete.jpg" style="display:none;"/></a>. Because only button click should be fired instead of whole li element.

@justin yes you are right. will go to hover.